# C#: cast to generic interface with base type

Tags: c#, generics

Here's the code:

```
public interface IValidator<T>
{
   bool IsValid(T obj);
}

public class OrderValidator: IValidator<Order>
{
  // ...
}

public class BaseEntity
{
}

public class Order: BaseEntity
{
}
```

The problem is that I can't do:

```
var validator = new OrderValidator();
// this line throws because type can't be converted
var baseValidator = (IValidator<BaseEntity>)validator;
// all this is because I need a list with IValidator<Order>, IValidator<BaseOrder>, etc.
IList<IValidator<BaseEntity>> allValidators = ...
```

How do I get and store a list of all implementations of IValidator<T> for base T - say, BaseEntity? Currently I do non-generic IValidator that accepts "object obj" but it is not good and not type-safe.

The funny stuff is that C# **allows** to compile:

```
var test = (IValidator<BaseEntity>)new OrderValidator();
```

but fails at runtime with

```
   Unable to cast object of type 'OrderValidator' to type 'IValidator`1[Orders.Core.BaseEntity]'
```

This is the same exception that Windsor gives me (I tried both Windsor and manual types lookup, this issue is really not related to this, only to the interfaces casting).

Thanks to Heinzi, I see now why I can't cast - because IValidator for Order expects Order as generic type. But how do I return a list of IValidator for different types? The reason is that the BaseEntity takes its real type and gathers all validators - for all types from GetType() to the object. I'd really like to have a generic GetValidators() and then operate on it.

Comment: Does C# not have wildcards (like `IValidator<? extends BaseEntity>`)?

Comment: If all else fails, you can use an `IList<object>`. Since `IValidator<A>` and `IValidator<B>` don't have a common supertype, I don't think you will have another choice... (But I'd love to be proved wrong on this point.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe it helps you if I explain why this cast is forbidden: Assume that you have the following function

```
void myFunc(IValidator<BaseEntity> myValidator) {
    myValidator.IsValid(new BaseEntity());
}
```

This code would compile correctly. Nevertheless, if you passed an `OrderValidator` to this function, you would get a run-time exception, because `OrderValidator.IsValid` expects an Order, not a BaseEntity. Type safety would no longer be maintained if your cast were allowed.

EDIT: C# 4 allows for [generic co- and contravariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/wriju/archive/2009/07/31/c-4-0-co-variance-and-contra-variance.aspx), but this would not help in your case, since you use T as an *input* parameter. Thus, only casting to an `IValidator<SomeSubtypeOfOrder>` could be done in a type-safe way.

So, to be clear, you cannot cast `OrderValidator` to `IValidator<BaseEntity>` because your OrderValidator can only validate orders, not all kinds of BaseEntities. This, however, is what would be expected of an `IValidator<BaseEntity>`.

Comment: Very clear explanation, this definitely sums up why it's best to leave all this work to a IoC/DI framework.

Comment: _“You can't”_ does not answer the question.  In the future, you're free to explain why the straight-forward approach in the Q won't work, but please also offer an alternative approach that will solve the OP's problem.  StackOverflow prides itself as a “Q&A” site, not a “Q&No” site.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson: The current consensus among the community is that [partial answers are OK](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144452/138661). In that case, I simply had no alternative approach that I could provide to the OP (see my comment below the question).

Comment: @Heinzi The current consensus among the community is also that StackOverflow has gained an unwanted reputation for being hostile, especially to new programmers.  _“You can't”_ (when a few more Google searches show that you can with C# 4) isn't helpful— it's hostile.  What is a new programmer to do when they're a week into building a system and someone on SO tells them “sorry, nope, won't work, too bad go home”.  There were solutions in 2009, and there are more nowadays and you provided zero help— **not a partial answer, a non-answer**, and an incorrect one at that.

Comment: @Heinzi My point is that the question wasn't _“Is it possible to cast to generic interface with base type”_; the question was ***“How do I get and store a list of all implementations of IValidator<T> for base T”*** regardless of approach _(direct casting may not be allowed, but there are approaches that do work)_.  The Q asker wasn't asking how the language works; they were asking how to accomplish a goal.  You shot them down.  That's hostile and unhelpful and a non-answer.

Comment: @Heinzi Side-note: If there's the question of whether a 9-year-old answer is still relevant… yes, yes it is, because of the Unity Engine.  I'm on a project using the latest 2018 version of Unity and uses .NET 3.5.  The OP is long-gone, but many have landed on this A since then.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson: Sorry, but I still don't see how my answer is incorrect. Please, feel free to add a better answer, and I will gladly upvote it. If you can point out *how exactly* my answer is incorrect, I'm also happy for the feed-back.

Answer (score 4):

The cast doesn't work because `IValidator<Order>` and `IValidator<BaseEntity>` are totally unrelated types. `IValidator<Order>` is not a subtype of `IValidator<BaseEntity>`, so they can't be cast.

C# does support multiple interface inheritance, so the simplest way to handle this is to make your order validator inherit from an interface for both validator types, that way it you will be able to cast it to either interface as required. Obviously this means you will have to implement both interfaces and specify how to handle the base when a `BaseEntity` provided doesn't match the type the validator is for.

Something like this:

```
public class OrderValidator : IValidator<Order>, IValidator<BaseEntity>
{
    public bool IsValid(Order obj)
    {
        // do validation
        // ...
        return true;
    }

    public bool IsValid(BaseEntity obj)
    {
        Order orderToValidate = obj as Order;
        if (orderToValidate != null)
        {
            return IsValid(orderToValidate);
        }
        else
        {
            // Eiter do this:
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This is an order validator so you can't validate objects that aren't orders");
            // Or this:
            return false;
            // Depending on what it is you are trying to achive.
        }
    }
}
```

This relates to what [Heinzi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749886/c-cast-to-generic-interface-with-base-type/1749979#1749979) says about not being able to cast because an `IValidator<BaseEntity>` needs to be able to validate `BaseEntities`, which your current `OrderValidator` can't do. By adding this multiple interface you explicitly define the behaviour for validating `BaseEntities` (by either explicitly ignoring it or causing an exception) so the cast becomes possible.

Comment: This seems related to my answer but my method avoids alot of the semantic restrictions and allows a generic call to ValidationFactory.Validate(myOrder)

Answer (score 2):

While this won't answer you directly, I'd recommend taking a look at the source code for StructureMap, they do alot of work with open generic types. Actually might even want to use StructureMap to handle caching of your validators, this is exactly what i do.

```
ForRequestedType(typeof (ValidationBase<>)).CacheBy(InstanceScope.Singleton);
Scan(assemblies =>
    {
        assemblies.TheCallingAssembly();
        assemblies.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IValidation<>));
    });
```

Then I have a factory class to do the actual validation

```
public static class ValidationFactory
{
    public static Result Validate<T>(T obj)
    {
        try
        {
            var validator = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IValidator<T>>();
            return validator.Validate(obj);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I wrote a big blog post on generic validation using IoC, if you take a look at it since you said you already use Spring, I bet you could adapt my work to solve your problem: [Creating a generic validation framework](http://dotnetchris.wordpress.com/2009/02/11/creating-a-generic-validation-framework/)

Comment: I actually used Windsor, and manual types lookup, both fails because of this issue (because interfaces are unrelated).

Comment: I added a link to a blog post I wrote about the subject of generic validation frameworks, I think it will help you alot to solve your issue and still be able to just call Validate(myObject) and have everything resolve right.

Comment: I use Windsor, not Spring. But I'm going to take a look at the article. And frankly I suck at IoC configuration.

Comment: You article is too simplistic. What I'm implementing, I need to create IValidator<Order> for generic validation, and IValidator<SpecificOrder> for derived validation - or even _several_ ones, e.g. OrderDateValidator, OrderProductsValidator... Now, BaseEntity.Validate() will fetch _ALL_ validators for concrete type - for SpecificOrder, for Order, for BaseEntity... and execute all of them, merging results. This is to separate unrelated validation classes. Thus, simple GetInstance<IValidator<T>> won't do.

Comment: In that case my solution would still be basically the same, what you need to do is exactly what you wanted. Create each of your validators OrderDateValidator, OrderProductsValidator by just derviving each class from `IValidator<Order>` except instead of GetInstance you would use  `ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IValidator<T>>()` which would give you all of them validators in an IList and then you could process them however you want.

Comment: Or the equivalent on Spring or whichever container you use, as far as I know all modern IOC containers should offer the GetAll construct.

Comment: After re-reading your comment what I think you're trying to do is incorrect, this goes the last line in the comment from @Heinzi explaining why you can't cast the validator the way you expect to. If you really wish to dervive all your validators from different classes of objects you might be better off just making physical class files that group all of the validators in the way you want. However IMO you would be much better off designing your framework that it can be handled by GetAllInstances.