# How to upcast generic type parameters

Tags: c#, generics

When I use reflection in this case, the created type can be many generic types.

```
BaseStepHandler<BaseStepDataModel> activator = (BaseStepHandler<BaseStepDataModel>)Activator.CreateInstance(....);
```

The created instance can be all childs of BaseStepDataModel.

`BaseStepHandler<OneDataModel>

  OR

 BaseStepHandler<TwoDataModel>`

OneDataModel and TwoDataModel are extending BaseStepDataModel.

this is the exception that I get:

Unable to cast object of type '....GlobalOnBoardingStepOneHandler' to type '....BaseStepHandler`1[....BaseStepDataModel]'.

this is the declaration if GlobalOnBoardingStepOneHandler.

```
public class GlobalOnBoardingStepOneHandler : BaseStepHandler<GlobalOnBoardingStepOneDataModel>{}
```

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - see the subject (I also added the exception)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I believe anyone should understand what OP is asking for..

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Now, yes, without the exception and the definition of the type, no. All well now though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the exception because `GlobalOnBoardingStepOneHandler` inherits from `BaseStepHandler<GlobalOnBoardingStepOneDataModel>`, not `BaseStepHandler<BaseStepDataModel>`.  This is probably the most common mistake with .NET generics.  Generics are not covariant for type parameters.

See:

[C#: cast to generic interface with base type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749886/c-cast-to-generic-interface-with-base-type)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/19/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-three-member-group-conversion-variance.aspx

etc...

The issue is that *you assume that because `GlobalOnBoardingStepOneDataModel` inherits from `BaseStepDataModel`, that `GlobalOnBoardingStepOneHandler` inherits from `BaseStepHandler<BaseStepDataModel>`*.  That simply isn't the case, and so you can't cast from one to the other.

As an example, consider the following:

```
var myListOfStrings = new List<String>();

// By your logic, this should compile (it doesn't):
var myListOfObjects = ((List<Object>)myListOfStrings);

// But if it did, this would be possible:
myListOfObjects.Add(1); // Holy cow, I just added an integer to a list of strings!  What is the world coming to?
```

Now, this is very confusing for recovering Java programmers because **this is possible in Java**.  In Java, you have type erasure, so that at runtime a `List<String>` is actually just a `List<Object>`, and so you can cast it to anything you like, and put anything you want into it.  Because the CLR uses reified generics, not type erasure, a `List<String>` is actually a separate and distinct type from a `List<Object>` or a `List<Integer>`

Comment: I dont understand, please explain.

Comment: There's no contravariance/covariance support for concrete classes' generic parameters. Maybe it's a mistake, but I find it more a missing feature, or an impossible feature.

Comment: What do you think is the alternative solution?

Comment: There is no "quick fix" alternate solution.  You need to revisit your design.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer it's an impractical feature; generic classes/structs are almost uniformly unsuited to co- or contravariance, though it's possible to construct some trivial counterexamples.  You can easily accommodate the counterexamples using interfaces, so there's not much benefit to supporting variance in classes and/or structs.

Comment: @SexyMF The alternative solution: you may be able to create a co- or contravariant interface to support your needs, as Matías suggests.

Answer (score 5):

Problem here is you're expecting <strike>contravariance</strike> *covariance* for concrete type generic parameters.

Basically, you won't never achieve your goal using a concrete type, but there's a workaround for this.

You can design a marker interface like this:

```
public interface IBaseStepHandler<out T> // "out" marks T as covariant
   where T : BaseDataModel // Do you have a model base type? ;)
{
     // Declare members here
}
```

Where I say "declare members here", just declare such members which are part of your concrete base class (I'm talking about "BaseStepHandler").

After that, implement this interface in your base class *BaseStepHandler*.

Now, you can do what you want:

```
IBaseStepHandler<BaseDataModel> some = new WhateverBaseStepHandlerClass(); 

// This is possible because T generic parameter is covariant and it can be casted to `BaseDataModel`, or if you don't provide a `T` generic parameter constraint, you could cast it to `IBaseStepHandler<object>` too!
```

In order to learn more about covariance, follow this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx

Comment: This assumes, of course, that he is only using his `BaseDataModel` in a covariant way.  If he isn't, this won't even compile.

Comment: @ChrisShain Well, but maybe solving his problem will force him to refactor his code, so he avoids this problem... That's up to him... I wanted to show him a way of achieve his goal, sadly no one can imagine the scope and what other problems will find him...

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong- in fact I'm upvoting you as I type this.  I just pointing out that this isn't a panacea.

Comment: @ChrisShain Absolutely agreed, it's not a panacea, it's a cookie haha ;) I understood you, and thank you for your upvote.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer `out` declares a type parameter as *covariant*, not *contravariant* as you have stated in the comment of the last code sample.  Mnemonic: "co" -> "o" -> "out"; "contra" -> "n" -> "in"