# Using Generic Covariance for return type

Tags: c#, generics, interface, covariance

So I have an interface like this -

```
public interface IBlah
{
    Generic<IBlah> GetBlah();
}
```

And I'd like to be able to return implementations of IBlah in the implementations of GetBlah(). Something like this -

```
public class Blah : IBlah
{
    public Generic<IBlah> GetBlah()
    {
        return new Generic<Blah>();
    }
}
```

I think this makes sense in theory - since Blah implements IBlah we should be able to return a Generic<Blah> in the place of a Generic<IBlah>, no?

But when I try it the compiler gives me the "Cannot implicitly convert type" error. I tried casting but I got "Cannot convert type".

What gives?

Comment: Generic types with type parameters are not automatically cast-able to generic types of the base class of those type parameters. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989629/how-to-upcast-generic-type-parameters for more info.

Comment: Question found by @ChrisShain provides both explanation why original code does not work and how to fix it for classes (if you want to) as well as  correct syntax (use `out T`).