# Casting concrete class to generic interface with interface as generic type results in invalid cast exception

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting

I have searched through several posts on the problem I am facing and I have found most similiar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749886/c-cast-to-generic-interface-with-base-type)

However, here we have a class as type in generic interface casting, and as I checked class SqlCommand inherits from DbCommand which implements IDbCommand. 
My example:
We have a Processor class which let's say have method Process.
Processor contains a property which is an interface of generic type described below.

```
public class Processor
{
IDbTools<IDbCommand> DbTools {get; set;}

public Processor() {}

public void Process()
{
    DbTools = (IDbTools<IDbCommand>)new Tools();
    DbTools.PrepareAndExecuteQuery();
}
}

public class Tools : IDbTools<SqlCommand>
{
    public void PrepareAndExecuteQuery(SqlCommand command);
}

public interface IDbTools<in TCommand>
    where TCommand: IDbCommand
{
    void PrepareAndExecuteQuery(TCommand command);
}
```

In this example, we will recieve an InvalidCastException, without compilation error. I don't understand why this is happening if SqlCommand inherits from DbCommand and it implements IDbCommand.

The approach that i made to make it works looks like this:

```
public class Processor<TCommand>
    where TCommand: IDbCommand, new()
{
IDbTools<TCommand> DbTools {get; set;}

public Processor() {}

public void Process()
{
    DbTools = (IDbTools<TCommand>)new Tools();
    DbTools.PrepareQuery();
}
}

public class Tools : IDbTools<SqlCommand>
{
    void PrepareAndExecuteQuery(SqlCommand command);
}

public interface IDbTools<TCommand>
    where TCommand: IDbCommand
{
    void PrepareAndExecuteQuery(TCommand command);
}
```

So my question is, why is it happening like that. Of course if we would implement

```
Tools : IDbTools<IDbCommand>
```

everything would work, but why it isn't in this scenario..

EDIT:
I am attaching sample at ideone.com: [Code](http://ideone.com/Aan2Ut) where is the same code just for copy past purposes into new project. Attached required namespaces.

Also adding the in clause, which isn't fixing the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Generics Inheritance Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909209/c-sharp-generics-inheritance-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your `IDbTools<>` interface with the [in keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx)

```
public interface IDbTools<in TCommand>
    where TCommand: IDbCommand
{
    void PrepareAndExecuteQuery(TCommand command);
}
```

See here about [Covariance and Contravariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee207183.aspx), Microsoft can explain it a lot better than I can

Comment: I have done that, still was recieving an InvalidCastException.

Comment: Whereabouts? This line is definitely incorrect as you don't have a variable name        DbTools = (IDbTools<TCommand>)new Tools();

Comment: Sorry didn't attached it into this code, was just testing this in my environment. I will update the question post.

Comment: I modified the code and attached code sample, still same error occurs.